# Access Fields of PHP Object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to access the fields of a JSON-File. The JSON look like:

```
{"ip":"83.215.135.170","location:"{"country":"AT","region":"Salzburg","city":"Salzburg","lat":47.8125,"lng":13.0504,"postalCode":"5020"
```

I want to access the latitude and longitude of this file. My current code looks like that:

```
    $data = json_decode($json);

    echo $data["location:"]["lat"];
```

I get the error that the index is undefined. Can anybody help me?

Comment: The JSON is invalid

Comment: Your example JSON is invalid: `"location:"{...}` should be `"location":{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a corupted JSON...here is the correct one

```
$json = '$json = '{"ip":"83.215.135.170","location":{"country":"AT","region":"Salzburg","city":"Salzburg","lat":47.8125,"lng":13.0504,"postalCode":"5020"}}';
```

With correct JSON you do this:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($json,true);
```

And now you can do this:

```
echo $decodedJson["location"]["lat"]; // Prints 47.8125
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access the fields like an array, you got to add "true" as a second parameter.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

echo $data["location:"]["lat"];
```

Comment: That would only work if the JSON was valid. Since it isn't `json_decode` will fail.

Comment: you are right, i expect op to just have valid json with a strange key.